# How can I use EditorFor with ViewData as source?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I setup a ViewData on my Controller such as:

```
ViewData["Registrations_Services"] = GetServices(); // return a List<Services>
```

Then, I'd like to show it in my View. Before, I was iterating using the model:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Services)
```

But now how can I do the same from ViewData? Tried with:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["Registrations_Services"] as IList<MyProject.Models.Services>)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(item)
}
```

But the type arguments are different and of course it doesn't works.

Tried also:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => ViewData["Registrations_Services"] as IList<MyProject.Models.Services>)
```

But it says

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

I need to apply the editor template `Services.cshtml` for each item:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label(Model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-6 checkbox">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RegistrationId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Description)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Enabled)
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>
```

That's why I was using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Services)`.

Comment: your **Services.cshtml** expects collection?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: looks the updated question

Comment: have you tried : `@Html.EditorFor(x=> item)`?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't render the correct list. The id only refers to the same name/id.

Comment: it's not quite clear, why are you now calling separately for each list item? What's the main view is binded to ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I'm calling `EditorFor` which apply the correct template for each item. Now, instead of calling from m.Services, I want to do it from ViewData. That's all, whats not clear?

Comment: ok, then you need is : `@{ var services = 
 ViewData["Registrations_Services"] as IList<MyProject.Models.Services>; }`

Comment: and then : `@Html.EditorFor(m => services)`

Comment: or directly: `@Html.EditorFor(m => ViewData["Registrations_Services"] as IList<MyProject.Models.Services>)`

Comment: Nope man, of course I've already tried this! It says `Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.`

Comment: then let's wait for some more expert to shed some light :)

Comment: Must you use `ViewData`? Using a viewmodel, with `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Services)` is much cleaner, easier, and best practice.

Comment: @JasonEvans Uhm, not sure what you are suggesting. If I create the class `RegistrationVM` in ViewModels folder (with `public List<Services> Services { get; set; }` as member), than I can't access to it via `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Services)` (it says `Registration` doesn't contain a definition of `Services`)

Comment: why do you want to do this? What's wrong with making the list part of your ViewModel? That's the whole point of a ViewModel.

Comment: Because I need to display a View with the model + the additional fields (ViewModel in your suggestion, or ViewData). Not only ViewModel (or only the View)

Comment: I have such as 200 fields in Registration. I don't want to "duplicate" them for adding just 1 member (the list). Lots of code and refactoring.

Comment: @markzzz Hmmm, strange regards EditorFor. Can you post the `RegistrationVM` code please? Using EditorFor in that manner should work, if the Services is public which it looks to be. Or just the section that shows Services, if the class is big. Also, can you post the `@model` bit that appears in the view file?

Comment: It works, but I need to switch the logic/view to ViewModel, loosing the original View/Model. Its the approch that I find absurd. Let say I have 200 fields in Registration. Are you suggesting I need to copy, paste and assign manually 200 fields? Crazy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the non-strong typed version, using the name of the `ViewData` key

```
@Html.Editor("Registrations_Services")
```

Note that this will generate

```
<input name="Registrations_Services[0].Id" ... />
<input name="Registrations_Services[0].Name" ... />
....
<input name="Registrations_Services[1].Id" ... />
<input name="Registrations_Services[1].Name" ... />
```

etc (i.e. prefixed with the `Viewdata` key), so the POST method needs to include a parameter with the same name as the `ViewData` key to be correctly bound

```
IEnumerable<Services> Registrations_Services
```

Having said that, you are editing data, so you should **always** use a view model, not data models in your view, and the view model would contain a `IEnumerable<Services> Services` property, making your use of `ViewData` unnecessary.

Comment: As a side note, you should be using `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Enabled, Model.Description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })` to associate your label with the checkbox